# WPF: How to make a Close button on top of a control to show or hide and clickable

Tags: wpf, triggers, overlay

I want to show a close button on top of a control only when mouse is over the control, and hide otherwise. Of course, the button should stay when mouse moves from the control to the button. So, I can't simply use IsMouseOver trigger or MouseEnter on the underlining control.

I tried to use a trigger on Grid, but Grid doesn't have IsMouseOver property:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- other controls -->
    <Button x:Name="closeButton" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0 -5 -5 0" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding HideControlCommand}" ToolTip="Hide">
        <Border x:Name="circleBorder" CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=circleBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=circleBorder}" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightGray" Padding="3" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid Name="parent" Width="10" Height="10">
                <Line  X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualWidth'}" Y2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualHeight'}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
                <Line  X1="0" Y1="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualHeight'}" X2="{Binding ElementName='parent', Path='ActualWidth'}" Y2="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Button>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="closeButton"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapse" TargetName="closeButton"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

This is very common in web app, but how to do it in wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datatriggers, i am using this one also for error  strip on usercontrol.

Style for stackpanel show hide.

```
    <Style x:Key="PanelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsException}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsException}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Stackpanel with close button where message(error/warning) will show ..

```
  <StackPanel Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource PanelStyle}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel  Margin="10" Background="Red" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LstError,   Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Width="18" Height="18"  Content="X" Command="{Binding CloseStrip}"  
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" 
                    Foreground="#FFEF0909" Padding="0" ToolTip="Close"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
```

in viewmodel you have to create a Icomand type property for button.

```
  public DelegateCommand CloseStrip { get; set; }

  //this is contructor
  public WriteOnStrip()
    {
        CloseStrip = new DelegateCommand(Close, CanClose);
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        LstError = "";
        IsException = false;
    }
    private bool CanClose()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use css to do this.  Just keep the opacity at 0 until you roll over it.

```
#test {
    opacity: 0;
}
#test:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Check out the js fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/qku6a/

Comment: Unfortunately this is WPF/XAML question